# Can't pass json object to contoller in asp.net web api

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

I am a newbie to web api,not able to find the error while passing json message to a web api controller. I am using fiddler client to post complex type(model object). My model is always null. It is not reading from the json post object. What am I doing wrong?

My model:

```
  public class LocationModel
           {


 public int Customer {get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }


}
```

My controller:

```
public class LocationController : ApiController
    {
[HttpPost]
        public bool AddLocation([FromBody] LocationModel model)
        {
            MysqlRepository reps = new MysqlRepository();
            if (reps.LocationInsert(model))
                {
                    return true;

                }
                else
                {
                    return false;

                }
            }


    }
```

Json message(post using fiddler client):

```
var LocationModel = {
Customer:9,
            Name: "test",
AddressLine1:"rrr",
AddressLine2:"rrr",
Area:"ddd",
City:"ddd",
State:"cooo",
Country:"kkk"
}

$.ajax({
 url: 'api/Location',
 type: 'POST',
 data: JSON.stringify(LocationModel),
 dataType: 'json',
 contentType: "application/json",
 success: function (data) {

 }
});
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Being new to fiddler tool i passed header info at body ...thats why input not passed from tool....
correct way is to pass in fiddler body as:

```
{
"Customer":9,
"Name": "test",
"AddressLine1":"rrr",
"AddressLine2":"rrr",
"Area":"ddd",
"City":"ddd",
"State":"cooo",
"Country":"kkk"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Saurabh Srivastava i fixed it